# MVC 3 Multi Tenancy and View compilation cache issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-tenant

I have an unforeseen problem regarding a sort of Multi Tenancy implementation in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Say I have 2 websites: `example.com` and `example.fr`. They are both served by the same MVC Website in IIS.

Then I have a custom `VirtualPathProvider` that, based on the domain, serves Views from different locations. The Controller is always the same, only the Views are fetched from different locations.

This all works well. The problem comes with ASP.NET View compilation. Suppose both domains have a View with the same name and path (MVC views path for clarity):

```
example.com/Views/MyController/Index.cshtml
example.fr/Views/MyController/Index.cshtml
```

This should work well. But the ASP.NET BuildManager (which compiles the Razor code to assemblies), caches the build **based only on the Virtual Path**.

So this means that when I first render a View while visiting `example.com` I get the correct view. But if I then try to render the View in the context of `example.fr`, ASP.NET considers that the view has not been modified (which is true as the Virtual Path is the same) and it will execute the view from cache, hence rendering the incorrect View.

A way to solve it is to maybe have the Views being compiled in different namespaces, based on the domain.

So far I got to `MvcWebRazorHostFactory`, override `CreateHost` method to return a `RazorEngineHost` with the correct namespace. Not sure if it will work because I don't think I have all the needed information at that point (`HttpContext` is one of them)

Anyone has any ideas? Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, It turns out to be simple to solve.

All I had to do was override `GetCacheKey` in my `VirtualPathProvider` and return a key string that takes into account the hostname.

In my case I'm simply concatenating the host and the virtual path and return the hash code of the resulting string.

Comment: Hi Pedro, could you possible put this code in a Gist or somewhere online? I'm struggling right now with compilation errors when viewing virtual paths on a second tenant and it looks like you might have it sorted - maybe it's just this CreateHost I need to worry about though...

Comment: I think it's the definitely CreateHost, as I am overriding GetCacheKey as described, and I can load js files from my tenant ok, it's just xshtml it is struggling with.

Comment: The downside to this concept is that as each domain's page is requested, you'll lose the caching that was previously done. So essentially you lose the benefit of caching the compiled view. Are there any BETTER solutions that will allow the framework to still cache each individual view once it's been loaded for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already gone down this path too far to consider other approaches, but I also have a multi-tenancy system I'm developing, and I've done it by overriding the view engine, based on Razor.

```
public class MultiTenancyRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the specified partial view by using the specified controller context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="partialViewName">The name of the partial view.</param>
    /// <param name="useCache">true to use the cached partial view.</param>
    /// <returns>The partial view.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="controllerContext"/> parameter is null (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">The <paramref name="partialViewName"/> parameter is null or empty.</exception>
    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        var searchedLocations = new List<string>();
        var foundFile = Support.ResolvePath(string.Format("{0}.cshtml", partialViewName), controllerContext.HttpContext, controllerContext.RouteData, searchedLocations);

        return foundFile == null 
            ? new ViewEngineResult(searchedLocations) 
            : base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, foundFile, useCache);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="viewName">Name of the view.</param>
    /// <param name="layoutPath">The layout path.</param>
    /// <param name="useCache">if set to <c>true</c> [use cache].</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string layoutPath, bool useCache)
    {
        var searchedLocations = new List<string>();
        var foundFile = Support.ResolvePath(string.Format("{0}.cshtml", viewName), controllerContext.HttpContext, controllerContext.RouteData, searchedLocations);

        return foundFile == null 
            ? new ViewEngineResult(searchedLocations) 
            : base.FindView(controllerContext, foundFile, layoutPath, useCache);
    }
```

I have my own Support method for finding views: "ResolvePath". I use the HttpContext as I have stored the site being visited (through the host name), and cache the result based on that host name (or the client's unique id as it is). It also allows me to do my own form of paths to search for a view, so I can have:

Views/Controller/Action.cshtml
or 
Views/Custom/[client]/Controller/Action.cshtml (or really very small partials)
if I want to override a part of the view.

Sorry, it doesn't really answer your specific question, but does it help at all? If you're interested in this approach I can provide more code.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, it would also work pretty well. I found the standard solution for my particular case and answered above for future reference.